# Toshiba External Hard Drive not being detected or even turning on

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, toshiba-hard-drive

Im new to this community but hopefully someone can help/advise me about this situation.

I have a Toshiba dtc810 external hard drive:

[image]

Bought it new 3 years ago. The problem is that suddenly the computer does not recognizes it, and the light indicator is not turning on anymore. Doesn't make any sound or something similar.

A year ago I accidentally dropped and hit into the floor but nothing happened then.

I removed the case and saw this particular HDD does not have any SATA/ATA interface, the chip with USB 3 port is pasted to the hard drive itself so there's no way to connect or test the HDD.

Do you guys can think in any option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not worth the hassle - just bin the drive and restore from backup.

Comment: Have you tested with a Micro-USB cable or another USB3 cable? You can connect any micro-usb cable to the left hole in the connector on this hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already opened it, look for loose connections, particularly near the USB connector. Often, the connector breaks loose from a PCB trace due to strain when inserting a connector. It might be possible to *carefully* solder it back, and there's an [instructive article on this type of fiddly work](https://www.instructables.com/id/Fixing-an-Arduino-Pro-Micro-the-USB-Port-Came-Off-/), and a [similar video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlqgujAj6ok).

Another option is to use [window-defroster repair conductive paint](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081DJPQSV) to bridge a gap between connector and PCB trace. This would be a short-term fix, if it works at all, but it might let you salvage data.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the crash history of the hard drive I would use a professional recovery service when you need the data.